# Making std::to_string work with void pointers, like operator<<?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, void-pointers, ostream

I have some code which `std::to_string()`'s a variable whose type is a template parameter. Suppose the code is:

```
template <typename T> 
std::string foo(const T& t) { 
    return std::string("I got ") + std::to_string(t); 
}
```

Now, sometimes this parameter needs to be a `void *`; and I would like to get the address in the string, e.g. `"I got 0xdeadbeef"`. No problem, right? I should get it just the same as if I did `std::cout << my_ptr`, right? ... Unfortunately for me, that's not the case. Well,

- Is it "legitimate" for me to want the code above to work as I described?
- Other than insisting on the use of a stream in `foo()`, is there anything better to do than to overload `std::to_string` for `void*`'s (using an `std::stringstream` in there for the `operator<<`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
namespace my_to_str {
  using std::to_string;
  std::string to_string(void* ptr){
    // implement
  }
}
```

Now `my_to_str::to_string` can be extended with your own set of overloads, like `void*`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't overload `std::to_string()` for `void*`, so that's moot.

But you don't *have* to use `std::to_string()`. You could implement your own that just falls back to using a `stringstream`:

```
namespace N {
    template <class T>
    auto to_string(T const& val, int)
        -> decltype(std::to_string(val))
    {
        return std::to_string(val);
    }

    template <class T>
    std::string to_string(T const& val, ...)
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << val;
        return oss.str();
    }

    template <class T>
    std::string to_string(T const& val) {
        return to_string(val, 0);
    }
}
```

And this *does* allow for overloading `N::to_string()` with whatever specifics you want (e.g. if you want `N::to_string(void* )` to do something special, just add another overload).

Comment: Can you explain that trick with the 0? I mean, why two overloads aren't enough? Also, since when can you have 0 as a parameter?

Comment: @einpoklum Should've been `int`. The conversion to `int` is preferred to the conversion to `...`

Comment: shouldn't to_string return oss.str() (not val.str())?

Answer (score -2):

You can make custom `operator+` for `void *` cases:

```
std::string operator+(const std::string &str, const void *vstr){
    return str + std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(vstr));
}
```

Comment: the void * is not a string, I can't print it as a string (I would need some sort of `as_hex()` function, or to use a stringstream); but your suggestion is interesting other than that. +1.

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast` is almost certainly wrong, and this would be UB.

Comment: @Barry how? If `void *ptr` holds null-terminated string it will be OK, in other case there will be UB even with `char *ptr` and wothout any casting.